# How would I remove the back line from the 3D- surface in \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I am trying to plot 3D surfaces using `\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot` in tikz-3dplot package. However, I get the lines along the surface even if setting the parameter `\pgfsetlinewidth{0pt}`. I was wondering if there is any way to remove these lines.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{135}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=0.9]
\pgfsetlinewidth{0pt}
\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[]{70}{40}%
{0.5*cos(\tdplottheta)}{black}{red!50}%
{\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
{\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
{\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!

For this surfaces (spheres) is easier to do it in plain Ti*k*Z. I use the `perspective` library with `isometric view` option, but these are not imperative.

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.616mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\tikzset{my ball/.style={shading=ball,ball color=#1,fill opacity=0.8}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view,rotate around z=180,scale=4,line cap=round]
\draw[my ball=blue] (0,0,-0.5) circle (0.5cm);
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0)   node[left]  {\strut$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0)   node[right] {\strut$y$};
\draw         (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
\draw[my ball=red] (0,0,0.5) circle (0.5cm);
\draw[-latex] (0,0,1) -- (0,0,1.5) node[above] {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't know if that would be a convenient way to plot other complicated 3D surfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another idea.

From the [doc of tikz-3dplot](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-3dplot/tikz-3dplot_documentation.pdf) sec 3.6.2, I quote :

`Syntax: \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[fill color style]{theta steps}{phi steps}{function} {line color}{fill color}{x axis}{y axis}{z axis}`

what if the line colour was the same or close enough as the fill colour?

`{0.5*cos(\tdplottheta)}{red!75}{red!50}%`

[image]

without the lines, the depth perception is lost.

Is this the expected result?

Comment: You are right... the lines are essential to see the depth perception. If I increase the opacity in \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=0.8]. The lines virtually hide but losses the depth. Apparently, the shading library doesn't seems to be compatible with \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot or may be I am doing some wrong.

Comment: maybe a gradient of colour would be more appropriate